# Using DTE Automation, how can I change the Platform

Tags: .net, automation, envdte

I'm using VS 2012 and am trying to use DTE to change the configuration to Release and set all Project's Target Platform to Any.

Can anyone tell me how can I change the Platform, as the property is ReadOnly?

Thanks
JP